# Is it possible to automatically copy a div's content as an input's value

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I wanted to know whether it is possible to copy particular div's content as an input element's value automatically when page is loaded.

Comment: You may need to elaborate on your question a little further....  But if i understand correctly, then yes, you can indeed get the content of a div and use it as a value elsewhere... 

What have you tried so far...?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
document.getElementById("myInput").value = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 3):

base on brso05's answer,

```js
document.getElementById("myInput").value = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
```

```html
    <div id="myDiv">some input value</div>
    <form><input id="myInput" type="text" /></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually modified the above answers, in order to get only the **text**, because they were selecting all **html** tags/Attribute e.g `<br>` `<p>` `<div>`

```js
   $("#text").val($("#my-div").text()) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-div">
<div id="first">THIS is first div</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <b>perspiciatis </b></p>
<div id="second">THIS is second div</div>
</div>
</br>
<input type="text" id="text"/>
```